# Onchange Combobox event not work in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, combobox

I have a problem when displaying JDatePicker of Jquery UI.
I want to display a different format when there is onchange event in Combobox.
This is my code, and it does not work when second onchange event triggered.

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr.golf_name").hide();
    $("tr.location").hide();

    $('input.type').click(function(event){
        var selectVal = $(this).val();

        if(selectVal == "tournament") {
            $("tr.golf_name").show();
            $("tr.location").show();
        } else {
            $("tr.golf_name").hide();
            $("tr.location").hide();
        }
    });

    $('#price_type').change(function(){
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        if(selectedVal != "none") {
            $('#golf_name').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#location').attr("disabled", false);

            $('#startdate').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#enddate').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#start_time1').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#start_time2').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#end_time1').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#end_time2').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#details').attr("disabled", false);
            $('#submit').attr("disabled", false);

            if($("option:selected",this).text() == "weekday") {
                // Holiday List
                var unavailableDates = ["9-3-2012", "14-3-2012", "15-3-2012"];
                // Exeptions if some Weekends are Working days
                var enableDay = ["3-3-2012", "10-3-2012", "17-3-2012"];
                // Weekend Days Sunday = 0 ... Sat =6
                var weekend = [0, 6];
                function nationalDays(date) {
                    // get date
                    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();


                    // if Holiday then block it    
                    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) > -1) {
                        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];

                    }
                    // if Exception then Enable it
                    if ($.inArray(dmy, enableDay) > -1) {
                        return [true, ""];

                    }

                    //if Weekend then block it
                    if ($.inArray(date.getDay(), weekend) > -1) {
                        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                    }

                    return [true, ""];
                }

                $(function() {
                    $("#startdate").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
                        beforeShowDay: nationalDays
                    });
                });
            } else {
                var weekday = [1,2,3,4,5];
                function weekDays(date) {
                    // get date
                    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

                    //if Weekend then block it
                    if ($.inArray(date.getDay(), weekday) > -1) {
                        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
                    }

                    return [true, ""];
                }

                $(function() {
                    $("#startdate").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
                        beforeShowDay: weekDays
                    });
                });
            }
        } else {
            $('#golf_name').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#location').attr("disabled", true);

            $('#startdate').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#startdate').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#enddate').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#start_time1').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#start_time2').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#end_time1').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#end_time2').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#details').attr("disabled", true);
            $('#submit').attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

**This is my HTML Code.**

```
<tr height=22>
          <td align=right>Select Price</td>
          <td>: 
                <select name="price_type" id="price_type">
                    <option value="none">Select Price Type</option>
                    <option value="2">tournament</option>
                    <option value="3">weekday</option>
                </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor=d9d9d9 width=800 height=1 colspan=2></td></tr>

<tr height=22>
          <td align=right>Start Date</td>
          <td>: 
                <input type="text"  name="startdate" id="startdate" disabled /> (yyyy/mm/dd)
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor=d9d9d9 width=800 height=1 colspan=2></td></tr>
```

You can view in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fanjavaid/uL7tZ/)

How to handle that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the disabled state instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like

```
$('#startdate').prop("disabled", true);
```

Read: [prop vs attr](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DEJB2/)

Comment: I mean, when i select `weekday` the Datepicker show saturday and sunday , and enable it. But when i select another, i want to show monday~friday and enable it. May be you can check the Fiddle above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here  var selectedVal = $(this).val(); because you Combobox is the parent so you need to get it's selectedItem.